# What is the server evaluation issue causing this EF Core 3.1 query to fail?

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

I've already learned the hard way that in EF Core 3.0, client evaluation [can only happen on the top level projection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/#restricted-client-evaluation) (i.e. last call to Select).  I thought I understood the issue but the failure of one query in particular under 3.1 tells me I don't.

This is the query

```
using (var ctx = new GsContext())
{
    var recs = ctx.Calibrations
                  .Where(ca => ca.DeviceId == deviceId)
                  .AsNoTracking()
                  .Include(c => c.Cartridge)
                  .OrderByDescending(i => i.CalibratedOn)
                  .GroupBy(r => r.CartridgeId)
                  .Select(q => q.First())
                  .ToList();
```

I don't see myself doing any complicated projections or anything that should require client side evaluation before the Select, so the exception message confuses me.  This was the text of the error message:

> The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression: KeySelector:
>   (c.CartridgeId),  ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: 
>       EntityType: Calibration
>       ValueBufferExpression: 
>           (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
>       IsNullable: False ) )
>       .First()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly
>   by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(),
>   ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I've already been hit with exceptions like this before when my queries were trying to do some complicated string processing early in the query (like I said, I learned about this issue the hard way) but that's not the case here, at least not that I can see.

I found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59346353/problem-with-ef-orderby-after-migration-to-net-core-3-1)  but in this case the guy was doing a projection within the GroupBy clause.  I am not doing that.

If it helps, here it the Calibration class

```
public class Calibration
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int      Id                 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int      DeviceId           { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int      CartridgeId        { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(CartridgeId))]
    public Cartridge Cartridge          { get; set; }

    public DateTime CalibratedOn     { get; set; }
}
```

I am sure I can work around this.  I'm asking to understand client/server evaluation better.  Can someone explain to me what I'm missing?  What about my query requires client evaluation

Comment: I am curious if this might have to do with ordering being ahead of grouping (grouping must preserve order for linq-to-object, but other implementations, such as EF, may not have the requirement to do so). I would try this: `ctx.Calibrations.Where(ca => ca.DeviceId == deviceId).AsNoTracking().Include(c => c.Cartridge).GroupBy(r => r.CartridgeId).Select(q => q.OrderByDescending(i => i.CalibratedOn).First()).ToList();`

Comment: Appreciate the try but unfortunately that did not help.  It did change the error message in the exception though.  Now it says  ***OrderByDescending(i => i.CalibratedOn) could not be translated***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59346353/problem-with-ef-orderby-after-migration-to-net-core-3-1) but in this case the guy was doing a projection within the GroupBy clause. I am not doing that.

Well, that's the problem, in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59347091/5202563) of the linked post I wrote:

> Unfortunately currently EF Core 3.0 / 3.1 **only supports** server translation of GroupBy **with projection** of key / aggregates (similar to SQL).

In other words, you **must** have projection containing only key and/or aggregates after `GroupBy`, otherwise it won't translate.

[Here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17068#issuecomment-573351215) is the related GitHub issue. And some explanation from the official docs under [**Complex Query Operators - GroupBy**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#groupby):

> LINQ GroupBy operators create a result of type `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` where `TKey` and `TElement` could be any arbitrary type. Furthermore, `IGrouping` implements `IEnumerable<TElement>`, which means you can compose over it using any LINQ operator after the grouping. Since no database structure can represent an `IGrouping`, GroupBy operators have no translation in most cases. When an aggregate operator is applied to each group, which returns a scalar, it can be translated to SQL `GROUP BY` in relational databases. The SQL `GROUP BY` is restrictive too. It requires you to group only by scalar values. The projection can only contain grouping key columns or any aggregate applied over a column.

Comment: Damn.   All that careful construction of my question only to be torpedoed by failing to properly read the phrase "only supports".  (Or apparently by mentally translating that into "doesn't support").  Thank you.