# EF Core: Get entities matching a filter, but only those that have the latest datetime property in their grouping by a composite key

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a table of entities of class `Pricing`.

Previously the `Pricing` table had a unique index based on 3 foreign keys: `InstitutionId`, `SubmissionTypeId` and `FeeTypeId`.

Now it needs to have multiple possible `Pricing` rows per that same index, but I should only use the one with the latest value of a DateTime column `ActiveFrom`, i.e. I should only use the latest active `Pricing` for the given composite index.

My repository method needs to return all currently active `Pricings` matching two foreign key values (`InstitutionId` and `SubmissionTypeId`).

I tried doing it like this:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
IQueryable<Pricing> filteredActivePricings = Context.Pricings
    .Where(pricing =>
        pricing.InstitutionId == institutionId
        && pricing.SubmissionTypeId == submissionTypeId
        && pricing.ActiveFrom <= today
    )
    .GroupBy(pricing => new { pricing.InstitutionId, pricing.SubmissionTypeId, pricing.FeeTypeId })
    .Select(pricingGroup => pricingGroup
        .OrderByDescending(pricing => pricing.ActiveFrom)
        .First()
    );
IList<Pricing> result = await filteredActivePricings.ToListAsync();
```

But EF Core says it can't convert that syntax into a valid SQL query.

I've found a solution using pure SQL code, but I'd like to do it in the EF Core's LINQ method syntax, since the rest of my codebase is written in it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59346353/problem-with-ef-orderby-after-migration-to-net-core-3-1/59347091#59347091 for workaround. Associated GitHub issue https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13805

Comment: Thank you @IvanStoev, you've pointed me into the right direction and I've solved my problem. I posted an answer so other people might be helped by it if they stumble upon this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out my problem and a solution.

The problem was, as @ivan-stoev pointed out, I wrongly thought that `IGrouping<K, T>` (the result of `IQueryable<T>.GroupBy`) contained a collection of `T` entities grouped by the key `K`, and that I had to somehow process that collection to get my single entity `T`.

So here's my solution which utilizes the `IQueryable<T>.GroupBy` method properly, to get a collection of key values and dates which are then used in a `Join` back to the table, to get the full data of the entities I need.

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
IQueryable<ActivePricingKey> filteredActivePricingKeyQuery = Context.Pricings
    .Where(pricing =>
        pricing.InstitutionId == institutionId
        && pricing.SubmissionTypeId == submissionTypeId
        && pricing.ActiveFrom <= today
    )
    .GroupBy<Pricing, PricingKey, ActivePricingKey>(
        (Pricing pricing) 
            => new PricingKey 
            { 
                InstitutionId = pricing.InstitutionId, 
                SubmissionTypeId = pricing.SubmissionTypeId, 
                FeeTypeId = pricing.FeeTypeId 
            },
        (PricingKey key, IEnumerable<Pricing> pricings) 
            => new ActivePricingKey 
            {
                InstitutionId = key.InstitutionId,
                SubmissionTypeId = key.SubmissionTypeId,
                FeeTypeId = key.FeeTypeId, 
                ActiveFrom = pricings.Max(pricing => pricing.ActiveFrom) 
            }
    );

IQueryable<Pricing> filteredActivePricingQuery = filteredActivePricingKeyQuery
    .Join(
        Context.Pricings,
        (ActivePricingKey activePricingKey)
            => new
            {
                activePricingKey.InstitutionId,
                activePricingKey.SubmissionTypeId,
                activePricingKey.FeeTypeId,
                activePricingKey.ActiveFrom
            },
        (Pricing pricing)
            => new
            {
                pricing.InstitutionId,
                pricing.SubmissionTypeId,
                pricing.FeeTypeId,
                pricing.ActiveFrom
            },
        (ActivePricingKey activePricingKey, Pricing pricing) => pricing
    );

ICollection<Pricing> pricings = await filteredActivePricingQuery.ToListAsync();
```